# javascript function when <p> value changes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

i have a section of html (see below) where the value in

constantly changes depending on whats being scanned by the webcam.

```
 <canvas id="qr-canvas" width="320" height="240" style="display:none"></canvas>
        <h3 id="qr-value">value changes here</h3>
```

I want a javascript function to fire when the value contains the following text -"Job". I have tried .onchange but i think im doing it wrong?

```
 document.getElementById('qr-value').onchange = function (e) {
      if ($('#qr-value').val() == 'Job') {
          alert('Changed!')
      }
    };
```

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: `onchange` works with `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements only:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your element has to be an input element, it won't work on h, div, span, etc.

You must have some function changing the value in there, so I'd just put the code within it after it changes the value.  If it's from a library, maybe it has hooks

Comment: thanks @WhiteRuski :) i changed my javascript to input into a textbox, tho it doesnt clear when i remove the image from the webcam....i guess thats for another day :)

Answer (score 0):

The onchange function does not work on h3 elements.  You can try and input, select, or textarea element instead.

Next, you can try putting the function which the onchange event points to inline of the html.

```
<input id="qr-value" onchange = "myFunction()">value changes here</input>
```

Then have a function in javascript called myFunction which does the check you were looking for.  Check here for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the `h3` is updated programmatically based on the input of the webcam, why can't the function be invoked by that very same part of the code when the value is "Job"?

Comment: what im trying to acheive is fire a function which pulls database information depending on the number after the "Job" text. i want to keep this seperate from the Webcam javascript hence not calling it together.